# docker-compose postgresql custom init script error

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Container log with error:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: sourcing /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mulitple-databases.sh
postgresdb                  | Multiple database creation requested: users,products
postgresdb                  | Creating database 'users' for 'user'
postgresdb                  | 2020-11-26 19:53:50.336 UTC [75] FATAL:  database "user" does not exist
postgresdb                  | psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  database "user" does not exist
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u

function create_database() {
    local database=$1
    local user=$2
    echo "Creating database '$database' for '$user'"
    psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
        CREATE DATABASE $database;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $database TO $user;
EOSQL
}

if [ -n "$POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES" ]; then
    echo "Multiple database creation requested: $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES"
    for db in $(echo $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES | tr ',' ' '); do
        create_database $db $POSTGRES_USER
    done
    echo "Multiple databases created"
fi
```

docker-compose file:

```
postgresdb:
   image: postgres:13.0
   container_name: postgresdb
   env_file: .env
   environment:
     PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
   volumes:
       - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
       - ./mulitple-databases.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mulitple-databases.sh
   ports:
       - 5432:5432
```

Maybe someone know how to solve this issue.
As i know standart init is running before custom script so when script is running user already exists.

Got a script from [this repo](https://github.com/mrts/docker-postgresql-multiple-databases).
Even with postgres:9.6.2 not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will sound like a joke but still there are 2 issues:

1. You will get error if your `POSTGRES_USER=user`. Don't know why but changing to anything else solving issue.
2. Also you will get an error with setted `POSTGRES_DB`

Hope someone can tell me whats the problem in comments. Thanks.